How to prevent my computer from freezing after overnight training runs
In my spare time I train ML models on my computer overnight. I typically do this by just preventing the computer from going to sleep and turning off the screens before I go to bed. In the morning I'll get up and turn on the screens and nothing will happen for about 5 minutes - the monitors won't even register that their is any signal. I'll wiggle the mouse around, press a few keys, but typically nothing happens. Finally after those 5 minutes the screen will show up, but it'll be as if I'm getting 1-3 FPS at best, sometimes worse than that.
Throughout training runs I track metrics about my system (through wandb),
and memory usage, CPU usage, GPU usage all look normal up until when I attempt to wake the computer, which is when CPU utilization shoots up insanely high (everything else is normal though).

Some notes about the training run: GPU utilization is around 20-40% throughout the run, with ~17G of GPU memory allocated. My machine has 64G of RAM, and for this run in particular I load my entire 35G dataset into memory (faster than reading from disk). Memory usage while the run is active is around 55G. If I allocate more GPU memory (~23G, by increasing the batch size) it typically causes my computer to stutter at other tasks including video playback, which seems like a separate (and expected) issue. Some more context: my OS is Windows 11, but I run my training runs in WSL. I have not experimented if WSL is the culprit or not (I do have a memory limit set in my wslconfig).
Another piece of context: in WSL I launch my training runs with nohup <command> & disown. It's a habit I picked up from work - not sure if it could also be a factor in this (I doubt it but who knows).
(Maybe this is dumb but, do I need more RAM? I'm not sure how to think about RAM - will 80% utilization always be slow, and you should always have 30-50% "in the tank" for optimal performance?)
It's as if the computer decides over the course of the night to dedicate all available resources to the training run, leaving nothing for actual OS tasks. Any advice on how to diagnose this?
I've looked at this question and this question but they're both over a decade old at this point, so figured some more up-to-date advice might be

Depends what process is taking 100% of your CPU at that time. That's pretty typical behavior of maxed cpu usage, but hard to tell what the cause is when all you're doing is reconnecting the monitors. Could be the gpu driver locking up for example. There's a power setting to turn off your screens after x minutes but not sleep, which might work better for you?

If the software has some slow memory leak, it's possible that RAM is exhausted and heavy swapping will occur. Especially if 35GB are already lost. You need to at least add a screenshot when this happens of Task Manager, Performance > Memory. (Add to your comment @harrymc for me to be notified.)
